# Wildfly 8.2.1 dies suddenly

Tags: angularjs, spring, postgresql, hibernate, wildfly-8

i'm having a problem with WIldfly 8.2.1. I'm developing an application with Spring 4, Hibernate 4 and AngularJS 1.4.8, using as environment Windows 10, running the server from console with standalone.bat.

The problem i have is that, when i publish this application in Wildfly 10 it works excellent, but when i publish it in Wildfly 8.2.1 (The version of the server that i am suppose to deploy the application once it is finished), as soon as i try to access any page of the application, the server suddenly dies.

What i mean by dies is, when i try to remove the application from withing the administration console in port 9991 ( i have it setted with that port) it does nothing and when i type ctrl+c to shutdown widlfly from the console, it starts by telling me:

```
11:45:13,714 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBA
S017535: Unregistered web context: /SGA
11:45:13,715 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1
-7) JBAS010418: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = SGA.war_org.postgresql
.Driver_9_4
11:45:21,238 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service
thread 1-6) JBAS010409: Unbound data source [java:jboss/dinaliTest]
11:45:21,247 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1
-8) JBAS010418: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = postgres
```

Does anybody know why this might happen? If it just the case that wildfly can't take the load that comes from an angularJS frontend or a problem with the postgres driver? I'm using a datasource connection defined in applicationContext.xml as follows:

```
<bean id="dataSourceTest" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/Administracion" />
            <property name="username" value="*" />
            <property name="password" value="*" />
        </bean>
```

Using

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.1212.jre7</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Does it respond to web requests?

Comment: It dies completly, when i request a new web those request are never fulfilled.

Comment: Are you sure the ports are configured correctly? It seems weird that it would just die.

Comment: The ports are right, it's weird because it works for some while and then suddenly crashes, i tried deploying in another wildfly 8.2.x in another server and it works fine untill i replace the war, then, sometimes the first, sometimes to third time i replace it, it dies. The sames happens in my wildfly 10 at developing environment where it crashes at redeploying for the tenth time or more...
I've never had any issue like this before

Comment: That's a bit weird. Are you seeing any `OutOfMemoryError`'s? Maybe there is some kind of memory leak somewhere.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in the answer, i am not seing anything, i've tried installing a wildfly 8.2.1 in a virtual machine with debian as OS, and i am having the same problem as soon as i run my application. And when i publish the app also on wildfly 8.2.1 on mi windows server it runs for a while, but dies at redeploying when changing version. i'm completly at a loss here. It seems like an OutOfMemoryError but it does not says so anywhere

Comment: Maybe you're hitting one of these issues https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-7037 or https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-6347. I'm just guessing though. Using a profiler is likely the only way to see what the issue may be.

Comment: Could be i am gonna try it. 
I've created a new Virtual Machine with ubuntu this time and now i got this error in the wildfly log
ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-12) UT005023: Exception handling request to /SGA/static/controllers/assisted.controller.js: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException